# cross compiling, why "checking whether we are cross compiling... no"?

Tags: cross-compiling, binutils

I'm trying to compile cross-platform tools-chain by myself.

When I compiled binutils-2.22, it success but why appear "checking whether we are cross compiling... no"? I suppose it should be "yes", right?

My host is i686 running ubuntu, and my target is arm.

```
~/telink_linux/build-tools/binutils-2.22$ ./configure --prefix=/home/shuaihan/telink_linux/tools --target=arm-linux
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnu
...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

After this, I "make"and"makeinstall", the arm-linux-* are created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not cross-compiling binutils; you're compiling cross-binutils. If you were compiling ARM binutils *to run on ARM*, or if you were compiling ARM binutils to run on a *third* platform (neither i686-linux nor arm-linux) then that message would say "yes".

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like I misunderstood the meaning of this message. Because my "build system" is same as "host system type", so it is not "cross compiling", right? Thanks!

Comment: That's right. You're building cross-*tools* because "host" and "target" are different, but you're not cross-compiling the tools themselves, because "build" and "host" are the same.

Comment: This is old, but there is a caveat not listed: Linux supports `binfmt_misc`, which allows this test to fail when actually cross-compiling; for example, `./configure --target=x86_64-w64-ming32` on Linux systems will sometimes say "no" to the cross compile check, if the system is configured to run .exe files via Wine without having to explicitly call wine.  To solve that, bypass the check by forcing it to not run: `./configure --host=$(./config.guess) --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

Comment: Errgh.  I typoed and cannot for some reason edit my last comment.  It should read `./configure --build=$(./config.guess) --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32` -- of course, adjust the `--host` for the intended target.  Sorry about that.